# crypto.randomBytes does not accept md5 generated utf8 string

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash, encoding, utf-8

My code is as shown below:

```
let createCipher = (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token;
    let keyVal = req.body.keyVal;
    const codeToken = utf8.encode(token);
    keyVal = utf8.encode(keyVal);
    console.log("keyVal " + keyVal);
    let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(codeToken).digest('hex');
    console.log("hash " + hash);
    var sharedSecret = crypto.randomBytes(hash);
    var initializationVector = crypto.randomBytes(hash);
    console.log("iv " + initializationVector);
    var encrypted;
    cipher = crypto.Cipheriv('aes-128-cbc', sharedSecret, initializationVector);
    encrypted += cipher.update(keyVal, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    res.json({
        status: '200',
        cipher: encrypted
    });
}
```

**I have written the above code as per the steps given below:**

1. UTF-8 encode the TempToken string and generate an MD5 hash of it.
2. UTF-8 encode the Key-Value Pair string and encrypt using AES-128 encryption using Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode. 
   a. Set both the key and initialization vector (IV) equal to result from step 1.
3. Base64 encode the result of 2

But the above code gives me the error as shown below:

```
TypeError: size must be a number &gt;= 0
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at TypeError (native)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createCipher (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\controller\test.js:17:31)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:129:5
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

Here my code does not accept **hash** generated from previous step in `crypto.randomBytes(hash)`. Is there any method missing in this execution?

Comment: *"crypto.randomBytes does not accept md5 generated utf8 string"* - Why do you think it should? `crypto.randomBytes` generates as the name already suggests random bytes. The only input that you can give is the number of bytes it should generate. What is it that you want to achieve by that? AES-128-CBC needs a 16 byte key and a 16 byte IV. Where do you store the key that you generate?

Answer (score 0):

`crypto.randomBytes` [takes a number as argument](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback), and it returns random bytes as the name says.

You cannot give it a string as argument.

I don't really understand, why you generate two times random bytes. Maybe this is sufficient?

```
let hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(codeToken).digest();
console.log("hash" + hash.toString('hex'));
var initializationVector = crypto.randomBytes(16);
console.log("iv " + initializationVector); 
var encrypted = crypto.Cipheriv('aes-128-cbc', hash, initializationVector);
```

Comment: But then how can I pass key and iv as I mentioned in the steps?

Comment: I don't know your algorithm, so here's a guess.

Comment: I tried your code, but it is giving me the error. I have updated the algorithm steps in my code,so is the code ok with that algorithm?

Comment: @Mthaker I fixed the size issue in this code (hex-encoded MD5 hash is 32 bytes long not 16 bytes long).

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV or one that is derived from a key (in this case same), because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.